# JS can not change variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to make reverse Int function which is as below.

```
function reverseInt(nx) {
  var n = nx
  const isNeg = n < 0 ? () => { n = n * -1; return true; } : false;
  return parseInt(("" + n).split("").reverse().join('') * ((isNeg)? -1 : 1));
}
```

Here in line 2, I am trying to change value of n id n is negative but it is not getting updated.
Please let me know where I am making mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: why can `isNeg` be a function?

Comment: You are not executing the function. A more readable way is to do those things in 2 separate steps. `const  isNeg = n < 0; if(isNeg) n = n * -1`

Comment: yes I am executing anonymous function if condition is true.

Comment: What a confusing assignment for `isNeg`! That's why javascript sucks sometimes. No value restrictions

Comment: @iksheth, no, you not execute, you just declare it

Comment: `{ n = n * -1; return true; }` should be `(n *= -1, true)`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir try typescript

Comment: You never call your annonymous function, it is never running.

Comment: Depending on the value of `n`, `isNeg` will either be `false` or a function

Comment: @Grundy Thank you. You are correct. I am just declaring it, not executing.

Comment: `const isNeg = n < 0 ? (() => { n = n * -1; return true; })() : false;` use an IIFE instead. Or better use `if` instead of cramming the ternary operator

Comment: Thank you so much all for you help. I found out root cause of issue, that I was not running function. Now it works.

Comment: `const reverseInt = nx => (nx < 0 ? -1 : 1) * (Math.abs(nx) + '').split('').reverse().join('');`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're never executing the function in line 2. If `n < 0` then you're setting `isNeg` to a function then using that function as a boolean value.

I'd recommend not trying to get fancy with things like this, just expand out the if statement:

```
function reverseInt(nx) {
  var n = nx
  const isNeg = n < 0;
  if( isNeg ){
      n = -n;
  }
  return parseInt(("" + n).split("").reverse().join('') * ((isNeg)? -1 : 1));
}
```

Comment: I know you are reproducing OP's code, but as a mention for OP: there is absolutely no need to use `var n = nx;` here, just use `nx` itself.

Comment: @Don On point! If `this` is not needed, curly braces would do just fine.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I agree, but I'm just answering the question, not gonna go into a full code review.

Answer (score 0):

I think youre going a little overboard with that ternary.
In the future try to keep your variables more clearly defined. You have here that isNeg can be either a boolean or a function, when all you really need is a flag.
The reason your n's value was never changing was because you were never invoking isNeg.

```js
function reverseInt(nx) {
  let n = nx;
  let isNeg;
  if (n < 0) {
    isNeg = true;
    n = n * -1
  }
  return parseInt(("" + n).split("").reverse().join('') * ((isNeg)? -1 : 1));
};
```